# LDAP search fails on server, not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, ldap, .net-core

I'm creating a service to search for users in LDAP. This should be fairly straightforward and probably done a thousand times, but I cannot seem to break through properly. I thought I had it, but then I deployed this to IIS and it all fell apart.

The following is setup as environment variables:

- `ldapController`
- `ldapPort`
- `adminUsername`  *Definitely a different user than the error reports*
- `adminPassword`
- `baseDn`

And read in through my Startup.Configure method.

**EDIT** I know they are available to IIS, because I returned them in a REST endpoint.

This is my code:

```
  // Connect to LDAP 
  LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(); 
  conn.Connect(ldapController, ldapPort);
  conn.Bind(adminUsername, adminPassword); 

  // Run search
  LdapSearchResults lsc = conn.Search(
    baseDn,
    LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB,
    lFilter,
    new string[] { /* lots of attributes to fetch */ },
    false
  ); 

  // List out entries 
  var entries = new List<UserDto>();
  while (lsc.hasMore() && entries.Count < 10) {
    LdapEntry ent = lsc.next(); // <--- THIS FAILS!
    // ... 
  }
  return entries;
```

As I said, when debugging this in visual studio, it all works fine. When deployed to IIS, the error is;

> Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\IIS_SERVER$'

Why? The user specified in `adminUsername` should be the user used to login (through `conn.Bind(adminUsername, adminPassword);`), right? So why does it explode stating that the IIS user is the one doing the login?

**EDIT** I'm using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

**EDIT** The 'user' specified in the error above, is actually NOT a user at all. It is the AD registered name of the computer running IIS... If that makes any difference at all.

**UPDATE** After consulting with colleagues, I set up a new application pool on IIS, and tried to run the application as a specified user instead of the default `passthrough`. Exactly the same error message regardless of which user I set.

Comment: `The following is setup as environment variables:` Can the IIS user read those environment variables?

Comment: Make a web page that just renders the environment variables.

Comment: Absolutely certain that IIS can read my environment variables @mjwills. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try going via Network credentials that allows you to specify domain:

```
var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
conn.Bind(networkCredential);
```

If that does not work, specify auth type basic (not sure that the default is) before the call to bind.

```
conn.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
```

Comment: The `Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection` does not seem to contain an overload taking in arguments of type `NetworkCredential`. `Novell.Directory.Ldap.LdapConnection` does not have a property called `AuthType` either. :-(